# Almost sure equality if $P(X_n = x \text{ infinitely often})=1$ presumed

Tags: probability, martingales

Let's say $(X_n)_{n\in N}$ is a non-negative supermartingale. From the Martingale convergence theorem follows that there exists $lim_nX_n = X_\infty$ a.s.

I presume that $P(X_n = x \text{ infinitely often})=1$ for some $x$.

Is this statement true: $x = X_\infty$ a.s.? If yes, how can I show it?

Comment: Say $S_{n\wedge \tau}$ is a simple ransom walk, when $\tau$ is the hitting of zero.

Comment: If you meant $\lim_n X_n$ instead of $\sup_n X_n$, then statement is true, otherwise is not true.

Comment: I made a mistake with the sup. Will edit it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it for each fixed $\omega$ for which $X_{\infty} (\omega)=\lim X_n(\omega)$. For real sequences $a_n=x$ for infinitely many $n$ and $a_n \to a$ implies $a=x$ right?

Comment: I think he doesn't take the limit but the sup of the process.

Comment: Martingale convergence theorem does not say $sup_n X_n=X_{\infty}$ a.s.. I think OP meant limit though he has written sup.

Comment: Right it is not clear, I thought he meant as a consequence of the martingale convergence we have that the $sup_n X_n$ exists as the sequence $X_n$ is almost surely Cauchy hence bounded. But the OP does not appear to be very active to clarify.

Comment: @clark Thank you for your correction. I made a mistake of writing sup instead of lim. I have edited the question.